# What is an IJKLMN Number™?

Tags: pattern, number-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with **Number** version puzzles.</sub>

---

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it an **IJKLMN Number™**.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| IJKLMN Numbers<sup>TM</sup> | Not IJKLMN Numbers<sup>TM</sup> |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 11 |
| 9 | 17 |
| 33 | 41 |
| 92 | 100 |
| 108 | 116 |
| 175 | 183 |
| 1,104 | 1,112 |
| 4,089 | 4,097 |
| 15,090 | 15,098 |
| 32,032 | 32,040 |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
IJKLMN Numbers™,Not IJKLMN Numbers™
3,11
9,17
33,41
92,100
108,116
175,183
1104,1112
4089,4097
15090,15098
32032,32040
```

Hint 1:

> [image]

Comment: does it have anything to do with the number 3

Comment: @MilesZew Hmm maybe not :)

Comment: then prime numbers perhaps?

Comment: @MilesZew check out what is "IJKLMN" meaning for :P

Comment: Ok, my final random guess is that it has something to do with divisibility of 63. Also something to do with the digits of the numbers.

Comment: rot13(Vf guvf purzvfgel eryngrq VWXYZA = U gb B = U20?).

Comment: @TheWizard Hmm nice guess :P

Comment: Do you have a further hint?

Comment: Does this has something to do with divisibility of 26(number of letters in english alphabet)? I computed and feel that it does.(or is this just a coinincidence?)

Comment: I thought that the rule might be rot13(n cnyvaqebzr va fbzr aba-qrpvzny ahzore onfr), but while that works for 3, 9, 33, 92, 108, and 175; I can't make it work for 1104, 4089, 15090, and 32032.

Comment: I've just spent days working on my child's nine times tables. I can't help but see a minor connection, dividing by 3, 9, multiplying.... There are patterns, I'm just not ... quite there... I Just K L Multiplying/multiples of Nine

Comment: rot13(gurl frrz gb nyy or cynprf va jngre, juvyr gur bgure cynprf ner ba ynaq. Rkprcg 183 juvpu qbrfa'g pbeerfcbaq gb n cynpr.)

Answer (score 5):

> A number is an IJKLMN number if it's a chemical with a PubChem CID (https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/32032)  whose structure contains some form of H-O.

Comment: 17, is a counter-example. :/

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to understand your explanation. Could you explain it using an example like 9 is an IJKLMN word and 17 is not?

Comment: @ThomasL This is wrong anyway because although it fits all the positives there are a few false positives but basically https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/<insertnumberhere> and see if it has an H-O.